# Are there options to improve the login speed and the general performance in TYPO3 10?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-10.x, typo3-11.x

### Introduction

We run a lot of **TYPO3 7.6** and **TYPO3 10.4** installations only as a Backend for frontend applications. We programmed several middlewares and extbase plugins to manage our data.

### Problem

After migration from **TYPO3 7.6** to **TYPO3 10.4** the general execution performance is significantly slower. For example to login a frontend user. **TYPO3 7.6** runs with **PHP 7.0** and **TYPO3 10.4** with **PHP 7.4**.

### PHP performance tests

First I tested the general performance of PHP with a small benchmark script. The result is, that **PHP 7.4** is around **30% faster** than **PHP 7.0**. I made this tests locally with docker containers on the same hardware. Opcode Caching is up and running.

***So TYPO3 should execute 30% faster with PHP 7.4. But it is not the case. It is slower.***

### TYPO3 performance tests

So I make several performance tests with **TYPO3 7.6 LTS**, **TYPO3 10.4 LTS** and also **TYPO3 11.1**. The general execution speed is very different. I installed a standard TYPO3 for this 3 versions, added only a login form and measure the response times.

| TYPO3 version | Action | Response time in ms | Times slower compared to TYPO3 7.6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7.6 | Frontend user login | 185 |  |
| 10.4 | Frontend user login | 759 | 4.1 |
| 11.1 | Frontend user login | 802 | 4.3 |
| 7.6 | Frontend user logout | 26 |  |
| 10.4 | Frontend user logout | 185 | 7.2 |
| 11.1 | Frontend user logout | 187 | 7.3 |

*All actions were run 5 times in a row and the average was calculated.*

### Questions

- How I can understand this behaviour? From PHP side I have 30% more speed but TYPO3 gets everything and need even more resources for the same operation.
- What are my options to speedup TYPO3 10.4 or 11.1?
- Are there configuration options in TYPO3 and/or PHP settings to get better performance?

**Thank you very much for every tip or hint.**

### UPDATE

This is the setup and the description of the exact measurement.

### TYPO3 7.6.32

#### Software versions

Ubuntu 18.04 / Apache 2.4.29 / MariaDB 10.1.44 / PHP 7.0.33

**Core PHP settings**

```
max_execution_time: 240  
max_input_time: 60  
max_input_vars: 1500  
memory_limit: 512M  
xdebug: Off
```

**Zend OPcache PHP settings**

```
Opcode Caching: Up and Running  
Optimization: Enabled  
SHM Cache: Enabled  
File Cache: Disabled  
Startup: OK  
Shared memory model: mmap  
Cache hits: 9544  
Cache misses: 694  
Used memory: 23044360  
Free memory: 44064504  
Wasted memory: 0  
Interned Strings Used memory: 2361632  
Interned Strings Free memory: 1832672  
Cached scripts: 686  
Cached keys: 1356  
Max keys: 3907  
OOM restarts: 0  
Hash keys restarts: 0  
Manual restarts: 0
```

**Zend OPcache Directive**

```
opcache.blacklist_filename: no value  
opcache.consistency_checks: 0  
opcache.dups_fix: Off  
opcache.enable: On  
opcache.enable_cli: Off  
opcache.enable_file_override: Off  
opcache.error_log: no value  
opcache.fast_shutdown: 0  
opcache.file_cache: no value  
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks: 1  
opcache.file_cache_only: 0  
opcache.file_update_protection: 2  
opcache.force_restart_timeout: 180  
opcache.huge_code_pages: Off  
opcache.inherited_hack: On  
opcache.interned_strings_buffer: 4  
opcache.lockfile_path: /tmp  
opcache.log_verbosity_level: 1  
opcache.max_accelerated_files: 2000  
opcache.max_file_size: 0  
opcache.max_wasted_percentage: 5  
opcache.memory_consumption: 64  
opcache.optimization_level: 0x7FFFBFFF  
opcache.preferred_memory_model: no value  
opcache.protect_memory: 0  
opcache.restrict_api: no value  
opcache.revalidate_freq: 2  
opcache.revalidate_path: Off  
opcache.save_comments: 1  
opcache.use_cwd: On  
opcache.validate_permission: Off  
opcache.validate_root: Off  
opcache.validate_timestamps: On
```

#### Installation

```sh
composer create-project "typo3/cms-base-distribution:^7.6" my-new-project
```

Setup: Create empty page

**Activate extensions**
about / aboutmodules / backend / belog / beuser / context_help / core / cshmanual / extbase / extensionmanager / felogin / filelist / fluid / fluid_styled_content / form / frontend / impexp / info / info_pagetsconfig / install / lang / recordlist / rsaauth / rtehtmlarea / saltedpasswords / scheduler / setup / sv / sys_note / t3editor / t3skin / tstemplate / typo3_console / viewpage

#### Settings

```
Configuration presets > Debug settings: Live  
All configurations: [FE][loginSecurityLevel] = normal
```

#### Setup

**1. Update Setup of root TypoScript template**

```
page = PAGE
page.100 < styles.content.get
```

**2. Create Folder for fe_users**

**3. Create a Website usergroup**

- Group title: test

**4. Create a website user**

- Username: test
- Password: [password]
- Groups: test

**5. Add login form to home page**

#### Measure response times

Use Postman to send requests to TYPO3.

**Login**

*POST http://typo3-76-standard.localhost/*
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

- user: test
- pass: [password]
- pid: [feUserPid]
- logintype: login

**Logout**

*POST http://typo3-76-standard.localhost/*
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

- logintype: logout

### TYPO3 10.4.15

#### Software versions

Ubuntu 18.04 / Apache 2.4.29 / MariaDB 10.3.22 / PHP 7.4.16

**Core PHP settings**

```
max_execution_time: 240  
max_input_time: 60  
max_input_vars: 1500  
memory_limit: 1024M  
xdebug: Off
```

**Zend OPcache PHP settings**

```
Opcode Caching: Up and Running  
Optimization: Enabled  
SHM Cache: Enabled  
File Cache: Disabled  
Startup: OK  
Shared memory model: mmap  
Cache hits: 71894  
Cache misses: 1146  
Used memory: 34302304  
Free memory: 99899120  
Wasted memory: 16304  
Interned Strings Used memory: 3942240  
Interned Strings Free memory: 2348768  
Cached scripts: 1120  
Cached keys: 2146  
Max keys: 16229  
OOM restarts: 0  
Hash keys restarts: 0  
Manual restarts: 0
```

**Zend OPcache Directive**

```
opcache.blacklist_filename: no value  
opcache.consistency_checks: 0  
opcache.dups_fix: Off  
opcache.enable: On  
opcache.enable_cli: Off  
opcache.enable_file_override: Off  
opcache.error_log: no value  
opcache.file_cache: no value  
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks: On  
opcache.file_cache_only: Off  
opcache.file_update_protection: 2  
opcache.force_restart_timeout: 180  
opcache.huge_code_pages: Off  
opcache.interned_strings_buffer: 8  
opcache.lockfile_path: /tmp  
opcache.log_verbosity_level: 1  
opcache.max_accelerated_files: 10000  
opcache.max_file_size: 0  
opcache.max_wasted_percentage: 5  
opcache.memory_consumption: 128  
opcache.opt_debug_level: 0  
opcache.optimization_level: 0x7FFEBFFF  
opcache.preferred_memory_model: no value  
opcache.preload: no value  
opcache.preload_user: no value  
opcache.protect_memory: Off  
opcache.restrict_api: no value  
opcache.revalidate_freq: 2  
opcache.revalidate_path: Off  
opcache.save_comments: On  
opcache.use_cwd: On  
opcache.validate_permission: Off  
opcache.validate_root: Off  
opcache.validate_timestamps: On
```

#### Installation

```sh
composer create-project "typo3/cms-base-distribution:^10.4" my-new-project
```

Setup: Create empty page

#### Settings

```
Configuration presets > Debug settings: Live  
Feature Toggles > Felogin extbase: Off
```

#### Setup

**1. Update Setup of root TypoScript template**

```
page = PAGE
page.100 = CONTENT
page.100 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}=0
    }
}
```

**2. Create Folder for fe_users**

**3. Create a Website usergroup**

- Group title: test

**4. Create a website user**

- Username: test
- Password: [password]
- Groups: test

**5. Add login form to home page**

#### Measure response times

Use Postman to send requests to TYPO3.

**Login**

*POST http://typo3-104-standard.localhost/*
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

- user: test
- pass: [password]
- pid: [feUserPid]
- logintype: login

**Logout**

*POST http://typo3-104-standard.localhost/*
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

- logintype: logout

### TYPO3 11.1.1

#### Software versions

Ubuntu 18.04 / Apache 2.4.29 / MariaDB 10.3.22 / PHP 7.4.15

**Core PHP settings**

```
max_execution_time: 240  
max_input_time: 60  
max_input_vars: 1500  
memory_limit: 1024M  
xdebug: Off
```

**Zend OPcache PHP settings**

```
Opcode Caching: Up and Running  
Optimization: Enabled  
SHM Cache: Enabled  
File Cache: Disabled  
Startup: OK  
Shared memory model: mmap  
Cache hits: 71894  
Cache misses: 1146  
Used memory: 34302304  
Free memory: 99899120  
Wasted memory: 16304
Interned Strings Used memory: 3942240  
Interned Strings Free memory: 2348768  
Cached scripts: 1120  
Cached keys: 2146  
Max keys: 16229  
OOM restarts: 0  
Hash keys restarts: 0  
Manual restarts: 0
```

**Zend OPcache Directive**

```
opcache.blacklist_filename: no value  
opcache.consistency_checks: 0  
opcache.dups_fix: Off  
opcache.enable: On  
opcache.enable_cli: Off  
opcache.enable_file_override: Off  
opcache.error_log: no value  
opcache.file_cache: no value  
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks: On  
opcache.file_cache_only: Off  
opcache.file_update_protection: 2  
opcache.force_restart_timeout: 180  
opcache.huge_code_pages: Off  
opcache.interned_strings_buffer: 8  
opcache.lockfile_path: /tmp  
opcache.log_verbosity_level: 1  
opcache.max_accelerated_files: 10000  
opcache.max_file_size: 0  
opcache.max_wasted_percentage: 5  
opcache.memory_consumption: 128  
opcache.opt_debug_level: 0  
opcache.optimization_level: 0x7FFEBFFF  
opcache.preferred_memory_model: no value  
opcache.preload: no value  
opcache.preload_user: no value  
opcache.protect_memory: Off  
opcache.restrict_api: no value  
opcache.revalidate_freq: 2  
opcache.revalidate_path: Off  
opcache.save_comments: On  
opcache.use_cwd: On  
opcache.validate_permission: Off  
opcache.validate_root: Off  
opcache.validate_timestamps: On
```

#### Installation

```sh
composer create-project "typo3/cms-base-distribution:^11" my-new-project
```

Setup: Create empty page

#### Settings

```
Configuration presets > Debug settings: Live
```

#### Setup

**1. Update Setup of root TypoScript template**

```
page = PAGE
page.100 = CONTENT
page.100 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}=0
    }
}
```

**2. Create Folder for fe_users**

**3. Create a Website usergroup**

- Group title: test

**4. Create a website user**

- Username: test
- Password: [password]
- Groups: test

**5. Add login form to home page**

#### Measure response times

Use Postman to send requests to TYPO3.

**Login**

*POST http://typo3-111-standard.localhost/*
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

- user: test
- pass: [password]
- pid: [feUserPid]
- logintype: login

**Logout**

*POST http://typo3-111-standard.localhost/*
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)

- logintype: logout

Comment: I'd suggest that you join the TYPO3 Slack channel https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C025BQLFA and discus this topic with the core devs.

Comment: How and what exactly did you measure? (This might be relevant so that someone can reproduce your measurements)

Comment: I updated the post with the setup and the description of the exact measurement.

Answer (score 1):

These days I am struggling with the `felogin` extension for 10.4 as well.

3 Tips, all  pure speculation, 1 year after you posted this:

1. Deprecation logging
2. PSR-14 events
3. Admin-panel

Perhaps it is "Deprecation logging" that slows things down.
I notice that in your setup you have set

`Felogin extbase: Off`

And this indicates that you want the old behavior activated, and the older codebase used.  However there are various (~10) locations in the 10.4 code that look like this:

```php
class FrontendLoginController extends AbstractPlugin {  

    public function main($content, $conf){

        trigger_error(
            'The pibase felogin plugin is deprecated since TYPO3 10.4 and will be removed in version 11.0',
            E_USER_DEPRECATED
        );
...}
}

// found in:
// public/typo3/sysext/felogin/Classes/Controller/FrontendLoginController.php:
```

2. There is also a new PSR-14 event-based replacement for Hooks and SLots. *felogin* dispatches several events. felogin emits quite a few events, depending on the action.
   https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-felogin/11.5/en-us/Events/Index.html
   I don't know if this is active (because you explicitly decided to use the older codebase, and PSR-14 events code is new code)
3. You can find out the time-consuming steps with the Admin Panel. Typoscript Tab, Settings Gear-Icon, "Display all times".